# What _is_ FFST?

Tags: java, ibm-mq

I'm running the same Java app in two Linux environments that are ( meant to be ) identical. The app makes use of MQ, and runs under a Java 2 security manager.

In one environment the app works fine, in the other, the app also works but produces a monster FFST dump in stdout.

To me, this feels like a difference in the level of tracing that is being carried out on the machine, but I'm finding it very difficult to get information about what FFST actually is.

Is it a process that will be running on the machine?

Do you start the Queue manager "under" FFST if you want FFST tracing to take place?

Does it run all the time but with a user controlled configuration?

Any clues will be gratefully received.

Dave

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FFST is "First Failure Support Technology" and these files are cut whenever there is an internal error.  Essentially, it is a program dump.  There is no concept of turning on or running under FFST.  If there's a program error, the files are cut, there is no way to disable that function other than to resolve the root cause.

The real question will be to determine what exactly is causing the FFST files to be cut.  The preamble of the files contains much useful information such as the process that failed, the WMQ module that it was in when it failed, the version of the module and some indication of the type of failure.  Below that is a trace which usually also contains the environment variables.  Evaluation of the FFST file, either by the customer or by IBM through a service request, usually enables a determination of the root cause.